# Datatype conversion failed for measure in PowerPivot workbook

Tags: excel-2010, powerpivot

I have a problem, during importing data from cube using PowerPivot for Excel.
When I import measures to the PowerPivot workbook, it treats numbers as text. When I try to  change datatype to decimal number, I get following error:

*The following system error occurred:  Type mismatch. 
PowerPivot database error: Datatype conversion failed for [Table: 'Query', Column: '', Value: '6198.9357860000009'].*

I'm trying to create pivot table with these values, but while it treats numbers as text, I'm not able to create it correctly.  Does anyone know how to deal with it ?

I will be grateful for any help.

Regards,
Konrad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I figured out, what was the issue. Regional language was set as Polish and default decimal symbol in Polish language was `.` instead of `,`.

I changed regional langauge to english U.S., reponed excel file and now conversion to decimal number is possible.

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't handle this problem, but I found a workaround. 
In PowerPivot window, I added new column and inserted following function:
`=VALUE(SUBSTITUTE(Query[MyMeasure],".",",",1))`
It replaces "." with "," and treats values as decimal numbers. Then I hid useless column (with text values) and renamed new column with hidden column name.

Comment: Does anyone know how to solve this problem in different way? Why PowerPivot treats decimal values as text?

Answer (score 1):

This may happen when we have NaN values in measures. Divide by zero errors will throw up exactly the same message in PowerPivot.